# How does the following code works(Dynamic Class loading from DLL)?

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, dll

I wanted to write classes and export them in DLLs and then later use them in my C++ application. I searched online and after a couple days' of research I finally found a solution. The problem is that I am not able to understand the code properly. I don't wanna blindly use the code. I wanna understand what exactly is it doing. Here's the code that I have.
This is the main application source `main.cpp`.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "ILogEngine.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibrary("LogEngine.dll");
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "LogEngine.dll not found!!!", "Fatal Error!!!", MB_ICONERROR);
    exit(1);
    }

    ILogEngine* (*create)();
    void (*destroy)(ILogEngine*);

    create = (ILogEngine* (*)())GetProcAddress(handle, "create_object");
    destroy = (void (*)(ILogEngine*))GetProcAddress(handle, "destroy_object");

    ILogEngine* logEngine = (ILogEngine*)create();
    logEngine->msg();
    destroy(logEngine);
_getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the `ILogEngine.hpp`

```
#ifndef __ILOGENGINE_HPP
#define __ILOGENGINE_HPP

class ILogEngine
{
public:
ILogEngine();
virtual void msg();
virtual int genLog(char *);
};
#endif
```

This is the `LogEngine.cpp` the implementation of the class.

```
#include "ILogEngine.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" DLL_EXPORT ILogEngine* create_object()
{
    return new ILogEngine;
}

extern "C" DLL_EXPORT void destroy_object( ILogEngine* object)
{
    delete object;
}

ILogEngine::ILogEngine()
{
}

void ILogEngine::msg()
{
    cout << "This is a message from DLL..." << endl;
}
```

I was able to understand some of the part but couldn't understand the whole procedure. Can anyone please guide through as to what's happening here?
Specifically what is `(ILogEngine* (*)())` part just before `GetProcAddress` and also preferably the rest of the code. I know it's probably a lot to ask but it will really help me understand this better because I have no idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

`(ILogEngine* (*)())` is a cast, it's cast to the type 'pointer to function taking no arguments and returning a pointer to ILogEngine'.

In just the same way `ILogEngine* (*create)();` is a declaration, it declares a variable `create` and the type of that variable is (you guessed it) pointer to function taking no arguments and returning a pointer to ILogEngine.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It does make sense but I didn't get `(*)` part of `(ILogEngine* (*)())`. Can you elaborate it a little bit more?

Comment: Think about the `create` declaration, suppose those brackets were missing i.e. `ILogEngine* *create();`, now that is not a function pointer declaration any more, it's a function prototype of a function called `create` which returns `ILogEngine**`. In the same way `(ILogEngine* *())` would be a cast to a function not a function pointer. Casts to functions don't exist (I think) but it's still the case that you need the brackets to make it clear that the second `*` is not part of the return type of the function butinstead indicates a function pointer.

Comment: It's essentially the same as the difference between `int (*)[10]` (a pointer to an array of ten ints) and `int *[10]` (an array of 10 integer pointers).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It cleared up a lot. Also I have quite some experience with programming but I seriously fall back when it comes to pointers. Can you suggest some practice or way to improve my skills in pointers' area. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
ILogEngine* (*create)();
```

This is declaration of pointer to function that takes no arguments and returns `ILogEngine*`

```
create = (ILogEngine* (*)())GetProcAddress(handle, "create_object");
```

`GetProcAddress` returns address of function with given name. `(ILogEngine*)` casts returned address (which is `void*`) to specified type.

After this, you have address of `create_object` function in your local `create` pointer (which needs to be checked for `NULL` - maybe function doesn't exists in given dll?), so you could call it.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic loading works like this:

- LoadLibrary: loads the DLL. The returned handle is used several things.
- GetProcAddress - maps an exported DLL function to a function pointer. You will see this function call along with a cast to function pointer type.

Note C++ names are hard to use, so the mapped DLL exports usually have C names.
In this example the `create_object` function was declared with `extern "C"`.

`create_object`, a factory function creates a C++ object and returns either the class itself or a known base class (more common).